# Autohotkey + Windows 8.1 + WInKey shortcuts --> Causes the Start Screen to pop up

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, windows-8.1

I have a AHK script with many shortcuts that I have been using for years now.

Most of them are based on the winkey, for example:

```
; visual studio
visualStudio  = ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk|Afx:400000:8:10011|SWT_Window0
GroupAdd ,visualStudioGroup  ,%visualStudio%
#q::
  DetectHiddenWindows, %MyDetect%
  GroupActivate,visualStudioGroup,R
  Winshow
return
```

When I use these shortcuts, sometimes, but not always, the new Windows 8.1 start screen will popup and then I have to press the shortcut again to get back to the application I wanted to go to.

I was wondering, Is this a known issue? Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting `ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk` into its own group or calling it individually? It may be possible that the start menu is in one of the classes you've named.

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf Thanks. But it seems to not be the case. I have other groups with different classes that still do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to fix it?

You need run the script as administrator, add this strings at the top of your script:

```
#SingleInstance, Ignore
IfEqual, A_IsAdmin, % False, Run, % "*RunAs """A_ScriptFullPath """",, UseErrorLevel
IfEqual, A_IsAdmin, % False, ExitApp
; Your code below...
```

Comment: nice! Thanks! So only admins can override that start screen hotkey? wierd...

Comment: Your script should have the same rights of access that the active application, or higher (that better).